# How to disengage from a Pokemon I don't feel is worth capturing?

Tags: pokemon-go

Tonight I was trying to capture a Golbat. After 11 hits, it kept breaking free. I decided throwing anymore balls was pointless. I felt angry about getting ripped-off. It seemed this Golbat was designed to make we waste balls. 11 hits and I couldn't catch it! 15 throws and it would not go away! Stubbornly, I kept throwing balls until I just decided to quit. But, the only way I could disengage was to re-boot the app.

Is there an in-game way to disengage from a Pokemon you are throwing balls at?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the upper left of the screen there is a "run away" button that lets you escape from any Pokemon at any time.

[image]

Comment: And hand-drawn red circles. Always good for bonus points.

Comment: obligatory link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FPELc1wEvk

Comment: @Federico your "obligatory link" idea makes me feel like there needs to be a tutorial on painting freehand circles.

Comment: To be fair, lots of times I had a glitch when all icons would disappear - including the run away button.

Comment: 2 more Upvotes for +44 and 44 Pokéballs !